# Intuition behind the Euclidean orthogonal projection

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection

Let $A$ be a closed and convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A$, and define $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ by $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}\|x-x_{0}\|^{2},$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $\ell_{2}$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The so-called orthogonal projection of $x_{0}$ onto $A$ is the following point on $A$: $$v:=\arg\min_{x\in A}f(x).$$ In other words, the orthogonal projection of $x_{0}$ is the point on $A$ such that the distance between $x$ and $x_{0}$ is the shortest.

However, I do not understand the "orthogonal part". What is the vector $v-x_{0}$ orthogonal to? It is clear that it is not orthogonal to every vector $x-x_{0}$ with $x\in A$, since $$\langle v-x_{0},x-x_{0}\rangle\geq 0.$$ Intuitively, I can somehow see that $v-x_{0}$ should be orthogonal to some kind of tangent plane at $v$, but I am not sure how to formalize it and prove it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In addition to the answers, you can also look at the concept of subgradient: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider the closed square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the four corners $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ and $x_0 = (2,2)$ we see a tangent plane may not be well defined. However the convexity ensure a [supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) will exist. Since $v$ is necessarily on the boundary of $A$ there will be a hyperplane through it.

However a supporting hyperplane can be chosen orthogonal to $x_0-v$. Appealing to the example of the square again we see that $v=(1,1)$ and here the orthogonal tangent plane will be the line $(1,1) + (-1,1)t$. Note that this is orthogonal to $v-x_0=(-1,-1)$ since $\langle (-1,-1) , (-1,1)\rangle = 0$. So of the tangent lines  that bound the square through the corner points there is one orthogonal to $v-x_0$.

This holds in generality and I'll leave it to you to prove it. You may also want to prove that if there is a well-defined tangent plane at $v$ then the tangent plane is a supporting hyperplane. The convexity of $A$ makes short work of the problem once you're familiar with the supporting hyperplane theorem.

Answer (score 2):

When $A$ is a closed linear subspace, we have $x-x_0$ is orthogonal to $A$.  In elementary geometry, where we do this in the plane, we take $A$ to be a line (or line segment) and we get $x-x_0$ orthogonal to that line.  I guess this is the source of the terminology "orthogonal projection".